# Datatables colReorder saving WITHOUT statesave

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) and am using [colReorder](https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/) and need to save the state of the columns without using statesave(I am not allowed to use localcache). I do however have a preference table in my database for storing this kind of information in JSON format.

I have looked at [colReorder.order()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/colReorder.order()) which looks like what I need to get the order.

What I'm thinking so far is on a column change, call colReorder.order() and place that returned array in my preferences table and then on re-initialization use that to re-order the table.

So my question/what I need help on is this: On a change of the colOrder, I need to save the order they're in and update my preferences. How do I do this? I can't seem to find "where" to place the colReorder.order(). I haven't seen an onChange() for datatables or even sure if that would be the best way to approach this

EDIT: David's answer is the ideal solution, however not applicable in my situation due to code already existing and laziness.

My [solution/work-around](https://datatables.net/reference/event/column-reorder) that I found was to stringify and save details.mapping from within this function to my preferences and on initialization of my table I use colReorder.order(savedArray[],true).

Leaving it in case anyone finds themselves in the situation I was in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually DataTables provide methods for storing and retrieving `state` to and from an alternative location. Look at [**`stateSaveCallback`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback) and [**`stateLoadCallback`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback).

> I do however have a preference table in my database for storing this
>   kind of information in JSON format

Then you just need to fill out the "blanks". Lets assume you have a serverside script called `statesave` that can store and retrieve the state by 'set' and 'get' using an unique `userId`. The skeleton would look like this:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
  stateSave: true,
  stateSaveCallback: function(settings, data) {
     $.ajax( {
      url: 'statesave',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { 
        action: 'set', 
        userId: aUserId,
        state: data 
      }
    })
  },
  stateLoadCallback: function(settings) {
     var state;
     $.ajax( {
       url: 'statesave',
       dataType: 'json',
       async: false,
       data: { 
         action: 'get', 
         userId: aUserId
       },
       success: function(data) {
         state = data
       })
     })
     return state
  }
})
```

Comment: Giving you the best answer as, ideally, that is the best solution. Unfortunately, the developers before be didn't do that and have every option saving manually. Perhaps that method didn't exist when the code I'm working on was written but I'm too lazy to refactor :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the `server-side processing` option. If that's the case, you can add the column reorder array to the [sent parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) object and save it that way.